# Finite order operators has pure point spectrum

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have to prove that the spectrum of an operator $T:H\rightarrow H$, $H$ Hilbert, s.t. $T^k=id_H$ has pure point spectrum. Now, it is obvious that $\sigma_0(T)\subseteq\{e^{i\mu2\pi/k}\}_{\mu=0}^{k-1}$ is the point spectrum of $T$ and $\sigma_0(T)\subseteq\sigma(T)$. However, I cannot find out how to prove that the two spectra coincide. I guess one has to prove that $T-\lambda{id_H}$ is invertible whenever $\lambda\notin\sigma_0(T)$. I thought I can do it in this way: $T-\lambda id_H$ is clearly injective under the assumptions on $\lambda$ (otherwise $\lambda\in\sigma_0(T)$). To prove that it's surjective, one may use the fact that $H=ker(T-\lambda id_H)\oplus Im(T-\lambda id_H)=\{0\}\oplus Im(T-\lambda id_H)=Im(T-\lambda id_H)$ (the equalities are isometric equivalences). Then, the open mapping theorem would imply the continuity of $(T-\lambda id_H)^{-1}$. Is it correct?

However, I'd like to avoid to invoke the open mapping theorem. Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint I was given, I prove that $T$ is a pure point spectrum operator. Clearly, $0\notin\sigma(T)$, since $T^k=id_H \ \Longrightarrow \ T^{k-1}=T^{-1}$, that is $T$ is invertible and its inverse is obviously a continuous mapping (as a composition of bounded operators from $H$ into itself). Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(\{0\}\cup\sigma_0(T))$. Set $T^0=id_H$.
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{T^j}{\lambda^j}}_{$=:S$}(Tx-\lambda x)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{T^{j+1}x}{\lambda^j}-\frac{T^j(\lambda x)}{\lambda^j}=\frac{1-\lambda^{k}}{\lambda^{k-1}}x=x.
\end{equation}
That is, $\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{1-\lambda^{k}}S=T^{-1}$ and the assumptions on $\lambda$ imply the well-posedness of the factor $\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{1-\lambda^{k}}$ and the fact that it does not vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can directly write down the inverse of $T -\lambda I$: Compute $(I+S+S^{2}+\cdots +S^{k-1})) (T-\lambda I)$ where $S=\frac T {\lambda}$. You will see that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible whenever $\lambda ^{k} \neq 1$ and $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think to use operator calculus theory in a "naive" way xD thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Your argument to show that $\sigma(T)\subset\{\lambda:\ \lambda^k=1\}$, minus the typos, is fine. It is part of the more general *Spectral Mapping Theorem* (the "polynomial version"s says that if $p(T)=0$ for some polynomial, then $\sigma(p(T))=p(\sigma(T))$).

But, it has nothing to do with the point spectrum. Your argument for the point spectrum is flawed, as far as I can tell, because you have not shown that the image of $T-\lambda I$ is closed.

I might be wrong, of course, but I don't think there is an elementary argument to show this.

One way to prove the result by using some machinery, is to use the [Holomorphic Functional Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus). Once you know that the spectrum is discrete, given $\lambda_0\in\sigma(T)$ you can construct a holomorphic function (a polynomial, actually) $p$ with $p(\lambda_0)=1$ and $p(\lambda)=0$ for $\lambda\in\sigma(T)\setminus\{\lambda_0\}$. The Functional Calculus then gives you an operator $p(T)$. As $p^2=p$ on $\sigma(T)$, we get $p(T)^2=p(T)$. As this is nonzero, take $x$ such that $p(T)x\ne0$; this is an eigenvector for $\lambda_0$, since
$$
Tp(T)x=\lambda_0\,p(T)x.
$$
This equality occurs due to the equality of functions $tp(t)=\lambda_0p(t)$ on $\sigma(T)$.

Comment: Which argument are you talking about? The one in the question or the one I gave in the answers?

Comment: You only show that $\sigma(T)\subset\{\lambda:\ \lambda^k=1\}$ in your answer, so "argument" in my first paragraph refers to your answer. You only talk about the image of $T-\lambda I$ in your question, so "argument" in my second paragraph refers to your question.

Comment: I proved that $\sigma_0(T)\subseteq\sigma(T)$. Then I proved that if $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(\sigma_0(T)\cup\{0\})$, up to a well defined, non zero constant $(\mathbb{I}+T/\lambda+\ldots+T^{k-1}/\lambda^{k-1})$ is the inverse of $T-\lambda \mathbb{I}$. This inverse is clearly bounded and the case $\lambda=0$ is trivial. This means that the only possible complex numbers in the spectrum are the eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Where do you use that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue? What you prove is that if $\lambda^k\ne1$, then $T-\lambda I$ is invertible; this is equivalent to $\sigma(T)\subset\{\lambda:\ \lambda^k=1\}$ (i.e., the Spectral Mapping Theorem).

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're right D: I guess I have to think to something else...

Comment: Anyway, the argument with the open mapping theorem is right? I guess there's something wrong with it, otherwise $\sigma_0(T)=\sigma(T)$ in the more general context of Hilbert spaces operators...

Comment: The problem, as I mentioned, is that you don't know that the image of $T-\lambda I$ is closed.